# Creating entries loop with nth loops across unordered lists

Tags: templating, loop

I'm looking for some help with the most efficient and performant way to generate this loop.

```
| COL 1 | COL 2 | COL 3 |
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
|   4   |   5   |   6   |
|   7   |   8   |   9   |
|   10  |   11  |   12  |
```

Columns here are unordered lists and I want to ordered by postDate going across each column. It needs to be done this way as specific to the design of the page.

I've tried `batch`, `slice` , loop indexes and experimented with range. Tried 3 different craft.entries loops to generate the columns.

What I would really need if it existed was `offset` and `nth` if `nth` didn't terminate.

I'm guessing answer will be something like creating these arrays outside of final entries loop and passing in IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided on Javascript for my solution on this one rather than twig. Reasons being that my entries still held their order in the markup and I can adjust to 2 columns if needs be for responsive breakpoint

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('projects').all() %}


<div id="columns">
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>


<script>

$(function(){
    var first = $('<ul/>').addClass('box').addClass('first-column';
    var mid = $('<ul/>').addClass('box').addClass('second-column');
    var last = $('<ul/>').addClass('box').addClass('third-column');

    var fElems = $('#columns li:nth-child(3n+1)');
    var mElems = $('#columns li:nth-child(3n+2)');
    var lElems = $('#columns li:nth-child(3n+3)');

    fElems.appendTo(first);
    mElems.appendTo(mid);
    lElems.appendTo(last);

    $('#columns').append(first,mid,last);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried a simple solution using javascript, you can translate the code into twig looping. I hope it helps.

```js
const posts = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
const colNum = 3;
const rowNum = posts.length/colNum;

for (i=0 ; i<rowNum ; i++) {
 const row = [];
 for (j=0; j<colNum; j++) {
   row.push(posts[(i*colNum) + j]);
 }
 console.log(row)
 console.log('----')
}
```

output :

[image]

---

improve solution using twig

@JohnHenryDonovan ah sorry, I didn't notice the batch filter. Why don't you sort the entries first, then batch them?

I assume you use bootstrap as CSS lib, then you can apply d-flex on each row.

```
{% set projects = craft.entries()
      .section('project')
      .orderBy('postDate desc')
      .all() %}

{% set grouped = projects|batch(3) %}
{% for row in grouped %}
   <div class="d-flex">
   {% for column in row %}
      <div class="item-{{loop.index}}">
         <!-- render your item here -->
      </div>
   {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The output of the code above

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="item-1"> ... </div>
  <div class="item-2"> ... </div>
  <div class="item-3"> ... </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="item-1"> ... </div>
  <div class="item-2"> ... </div>
  <div class="item-3"> ... </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="item-1"> ... </div>
  <div class="item-2"> ... </div>
  <div class="item-3"> ... </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle HTML output http://jsfiddle.net/30k9ndg6/3/

Comment: Wouldn't this just be the same as `batch`? 


`{% set columns = projects|batch(3) %}`


I need to figure out how to get the following essentially using your JS as an example


`const posts = [1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11,3,6,9,12];`

Comment: I think Im gonna go Javascript route in this. It will keep my entry list clean and allow me to adjust columns in mobile. Similar to http://jsfiddle.net/UrVsR/1/

Comment: @JohnHenryDonovan see my updated answer above

Comment: Thanks but that wont work. See my original diagram  That will just flow entries into 3 columns like col1 - 1,2,3,4 col2 -  5,6,7,8, col3 - 9,10,11,12. I have it working now with JS though